# Как проверить строку на наличие последнего символа?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, dart

подскажите как проверить строку на наличие символа.
Например var num = 1234;
Как сделать условие что если строка содержит Последний символ '4' то сделать такое то действие. Мне нужна проверка именно последнего символа. в интернете не могу найти ничего похожего.

Comment: на C# так: `if (str.Last() == '4') ...`

Comment: и определитесь с языком программирования

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Плохо искали... и определитесь с языком

***JS***

```
if (str.endsWith("?")) {
    //...
}
```

***JAVA***

```
if (str.endsWith("?")) {
    //...
}
```

***C#***

```
if (str.EndsWith("?")) {
    //...
}
```

***dart***

```
if (str.endsWith("?")) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: язык Дарт, но поскольку он взял в себя с js java и с-подобных, так что спрашиваю по этим языкам. Уже сделал немного по другому но за идею спасибо

Comment: @nikitasalnikov, как правило открываете документацию по языку, к примеру по строкам в dart или еще где-то и там будет перечисление всех свойств и методов. Можно пробовать найти на русском перечесление, если с английским не очень, типа такого: http://dartdot.ru/Библиотеки/Основная_библиотека_dart_core/String/9.html Для базовых операций в большинстве случаев будет что-то готовое. Если там ничего подходящего нет, то тогда уже можно поискать где-то еще.

Comment: по дарту не могу найти документацию на русском. на метаните сказали что устаревшая документалка. во многих видосах тоже смотрю и устаревшие методики. Поэтому приходится спрашивать или очень очень долго переводить с помощью переводчика